# Use single color for all series in the same chart

Tags: colors, highcharts

How can I set the same color for all the series in a single chart? I have a huge number of series in my chart and it can be inconvenient to set the color for each of the series individually.

Let's say I want all the series of my chart to be `red` colored, how do I go about doing this without needing to explicitly set the `series.color` to `red` each time?

Comment: I don't understand how come this question was closed, it is obvious that OP wants to have all lines in same color and doesn't want to set the color of each series individually, he rather wants to do it via single setting. Maybe the sentence 'I have a huge number of series in my chart and can be inconvenient to set the same color for each series' was confusing to someone but if that's the case the OP should have been notified to give proper explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it they way Jeremy mentioned, by setting the colors options for each chart. Or you can override the default color array as follows

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors:['red','green','blue']
});
```

The benefit of this approach is you only have to call this once, before create any chart. And all charts after this will use these colors, without you needing to set this option on each chart. Most of the websites have a common.js or a similar javascript file that is generally loaded before any other custom script, you just need to add this code to that file and forget about the colors thereafter

**Update**
Since you want all series in the same chart to be of a single color, you can override the colors array completely and make it have only one color

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = ['red'];
```

This method will leave the navigator (blue mini graph at bottom in Highstock) to be of default blue color, this has to be overriden in a different way from options.

*P.S. the above way is not the recommended way of overriding default options, correct way would be to do `setOptions()`, but that would cause a merge with existing defaults and hence the array size would be more than 1.*

**Alternately**, you can just override the getColor method as follows, to always return the color of your choice. Again you need to do this before you call the chart's constructor

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.getColor=function(){
    this.color= '#f00';
}
```

[**Setting default colors @ jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/4YXdP)

Comment: I don't want to declare: colors:['red','red','red','red','red', (200 times) ];. I'm asking if I can put in some code line colorforall:['red']; and stop. And yes, I have 200 series and more in a single chart.

Comment: @Tic Ohk, so you want all series in the chart to be of same color?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array of hex colors, and then use that array in your chart declaration. All series in the chart object will pull from this array of colors.

If you have multiple chart declarations, you can just use the same array.

Here's one of the Highcharts samples, with an array of custom colors added ([run with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwEKF/)):

```
$(function () {
    var myColors = [
        '#ff0000',
        '#ff6600',
        '#ffcc00'
    ];
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            colors: myColors,
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked bar chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                reversed: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to declare: var mycolors=['red','red','red','red','red', (200 times) ];. I'm asking if I can put in some code line colorforall:'red'; and stop. And yes, I have 200 series and more in a single chart.